# Count the occurrences of factors per column in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix (10000 columns and 600 rows), an example is shown below, containing nucleotides, but also NAs. I would like to count the number of occurrences of each nucleotide (factor) for each column but ignoring the NAs. The output should be in a List.

```
`r1 <- c("a","c","a","a","t","c")
 r2 <- c("a","c","t","t","c","a")
 r3 <- c("a","g","g","c","a","c")
 r4 <- c("a","g","g","g","g","c")
 r5<- c(NA, "g","g","g","t","g")

 n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)`
```

The output should be in a List containing only the occurrences of each nucleotide in each column. So each List element should contain the numbers of one column.

```
[[1]]
[1] "4"
[[2]]
[2] "2" "3"
[[3]]
[3] "1" "1" "3"
[[4]]
[4] "1" "1" "1" "2"
[[4]]
[4] "2" "1" "1" "1"
[[5]]
[5] "3" "1" "1"
```

I was already trying to find a solution, but I don't know how to actually count the number of occurrences per column in a matrix. My code is:

```
alleles_nmat <- apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Notice that `"NA"` isn't `NA`, `NA` is (without quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
apply(n.mat, 2, table)
[[1]]

 a NA 
 4  1 

[[2]]

c g  
2 3 

[[3]]

a g t 
1 3 1 

[[4]]

a c g t 
1 1 2 1 

[[5]]

a c g t 
1 1 1 2 

[[6]]

a c g 
1 3 1
```

Comment: Yes this is somehow what I want, expect, that the table function doesn't work on my matrix since it is too big, and second, I would like to ignore NAs. So I don't want to see them in the list later on.

Comment: The function ignores `NA` by default. In your matrix however you do not have `NA` as missing values, you have `"NA"` as character values. `NA` is different than `"NA"`